# Arguments not properly passed to function

Tags: function, class, lua

I am new to Lua, and I downloaded and wanted to use the class.lua file from [this link](https://github.com/vrld/hump/blob/master/class.lua).
However, when I attempt to call the Board:addSign function from anywhere, no matter what I do, the arguments passed are the value of the place variable and nil instead of the values of the sign and place variables. How would I go around fixing that?

Here's my code, both main and the class itself.

```
Class = require 'class'
require 'Board'

board = Board()

for place = 1, 9 do
  print('Input sign: ')
  sign = io.read()
  board.addSign(sign, place)
end
```

```
Board = Class{}

function Board:init()
  array = {}
  for n = 1, 9 do
    array[n] = ' '
  end
  --
  self.array = array
end

function Board:addSign(sign, place)
  print(sign) -- outputs whatever I passed as place
  print(place) -- outputs nil no matter what
  self.array[place] = sign -- crashes here since place is nil
end
```

Comment: you missed a very important concept in Lua. please revisit the basics about function definitions and function calls. https://www.lua.org/manual/5.4/manual.html

Answer (score 1):

Use `board:addSign` instead of `board.addSign`.

Answer (score 0):

```
function Board:addSign(sign, place) end
```

is syntactic sugar for

```
function Board.addSign(self, sign, place) end
```

This allows you to do things like  `self.array[place] = sign` inside that function.

So you defined a function with 3 parameters but you only provide 2 when calling it.

```
board.addSign(sign, place)
```

Inside your function that basically results in

```
local self = sign
local sign = place
local place = nil
```

So either call `Board:addSign(sign, place)` or `Board.addSign(Board, sign, place)`

Comment: I figured it was something along these lines, but couldn't quite put my finger on what exactly the problem was.
Thank you very much for clarifying it, I appreciate it!